# C# Serializing from generic base class with XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have a class declared more or less as such:

```
public class XmlDataFormatter<MyNativeData> : IDataFromatter<MyNativeData> where MyNativeData : class 
{
   ...
   public XmlDataFormatter() { ... } //Default constructor
   ...
   public virtual MyNativeData Deserialize(string xml)
   {
      try 
      {
         xml.Deserialize<MyNativeData>(); // Throws exception
      }
      catch(Exception){}
   }
   ...
} //end of class
```

The xml string is generated from other code that creates similar XML files but nonetheless different enough and numerous enough to avoid wanting to create a serializable class for each variation. The idea is to take the XML and create an object automatically from all the elements present in the file.

This code is called in a controller, say MyController.

**The Exception**

System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: 'Type 'MyController + MyNativeData' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required

**The Problem**

I only have declared `MyNativeData` inline and so I wouldn't know where to put any `DataContractAttribute` and my class and methods are already public.

this error only occurs at runtime.

**Question**

Is there a way to serialize the xml string the way I'm doing it?

Comment: Since you are using the `DataContractSerializer`, you might consider adding the `wcf` tag. Is `Deserialize<T>()` an extension method on string?  I've only ever done this kind of thing using a `DataContractSerializer` object.  Why is your `Deserialize` method virtual; do you have subclasses? Why is it declared to return a `MyNativeData` object, but it doesn't return anything?  What does _"I only have declared MyNativeData inline"_ mean here?  All this is a little hard to folllow.

Comment: Are you using an xml serializer or a binary serializer?